# Relative modules were not found with svg sprite loader, Vue.js & webpack2

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack, vue.js

I’m trying to add svg-sprite-loader to my project, but i keep getting this error, where it can’t find the modules. Can anyone help me clarify why this is happening?

**Error**

> These relative modules were not found:
>
> ./wrench.svg in ./src/assets/svg ^./.*.svg$ 
>   …

**build/webpack.base.conf.js**

```
{
     test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)(\?.*)?$/, // removed svg from the list
     loader: 'url-loader',
     options: {
         limit: 10000,
         name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
     }
},
{
     test: /\.svg(\?.*)?$/,
         loader: 'svg-sprite?' + JSON.stringify({
             name: '[name]_[hash]',
             spriteModule: 'utils/sprite',
             prefixize: true
         })
}
```

**build/utils/sprite.js**

```
var Sprite = require('svg-sprite-loader/lib/web/sprite')

// Remove visibility:hidden
Sprite.styles.pop()
Sprite.styles.push('display:none')

var globalSprite = new Sprite()

if (document.body) {
  globalSprite.elem = globalSprite.render(document.body)
} else {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    globalSprite.elem = globalSprite.render(document.body)
  }, false)
}

module.exports = globalSprite
```

**src/main.js**

```
import Icon from './icon.vue'
Vue.component('icon', Icon)
```

**src/icon.vue**

```
  <svg class="icon" :class="'icon-' + name">
    <use :xlink:href="xlink"/>
  </svg>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['name'],
    computed: {
        xlink () {
            return require(`./assets/svg/` + `${this.name}.svg`)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

If i try to import an icon from a relative path, i get the following error:

```
import share from './assets/svg/share.svg'
```

> This relative module was not found: 
>   *./src/assets/svg/share.svg in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index?0&bustCache!./src/icon.vue

Answer (score 0):

(1) You can try removing the cache-folder in nodemodules: `node_modules/.cache`

(2) You can also try using an @ in the require(). In the case below, the program will search in `src/assets/svg/` for your svg-file:

```
require(`@/assets/svg/${this.name}.svg`)
```

I hope this helps for you.. I had the same error and the second solution fixed it for me.
https://www.thecodingcouple.com/vue-js-error-this-relative-module-was-not-found/